# Running one project from another in one solution (Visual studio)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have  two projects in my VS solution: WPF app and c# console app.
I would like to run WPF app, when user puts "GUI" in console app. Can I do it in easy way?

Comment: What do uou mean by "puts"?

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

string wpfApp = "this/and/that/my-wpf-app.exe";

if (command == "GUI")
    Process.Start(wpfApp);
```